# Confused about vuex getters: How to return a function

Tags: vuex

According to the Vuex documentation, You can also pass arguments to getters by returning a function. [enter link description here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html)

But I have a problem.In my case, there is a student list, and I want to find the student by id. Below is my code:

```
//store.js
export const store = {
  state: {
    students: [
      { name: 'Wang Pengfei', id: 0, sex: 'male' },
      { name: 'Tang Weijuan', id: 1, sex: 'female' },
      { name: 'Xiao Ming', id: 2, sex: 'male' },
      { name: 'Xiao Hong', id: 3, sex: 'female' }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    getStudentById: function(state){
      return function(id){
        return state.students.find(st => st.id === id);
      }
    }
  }
};
```

But When I try to access this getter in my component, I get a text string of return function.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input name="indexInput" @input="inputChange" value="0"/>
    <!-- This line will be rendered as 'The students you find is function (id) { return state.students.find(function (st) { return st.id === id; }); }'-->     
    <span>The students you find is {{objectStudent}}</span>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      stId: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    inputChange(event) {
      this.stId = event.target.value;
    }
  },
  computed: {
    //return the code of function as a text string, why???
    objectStudent() {
      return this.$store.getters.getStudentById(this.stId);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: So adding console.log('test') before `return state.students.find(st => st.id === id);` does not output anything at all in console?

Comment: Yes, if I add `console.log` before `return state.students.find(st => st.id === id);`, it does not output anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve the problem.The way I create the store is wrong, I should use `new Vuex.Store()` instead of creating directly by `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getters: {
  getStudentById: (state) => (id) => state.students.find(st => st.id === id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer is essentially the same as mine, So the result is same.